# MS Access Retrieve Values from ListBox

Tags: vba, ms-access

UPDATE: 3/20/2019
After subthread conversation (below), I renamed the ListBox. ItemsSelected property WORKS. Value still returning NULL int he code

---

This is my first time dealing with multi-select lists in Access. I have a report form with some dropdowns, checkboxes, and a listbox. The listbox contains almost 70 items - Let's call them "Cities".

The ListBox allows multiple selections. In VBA, I'm taking each of the parameters - from the other controls on the form, to create a giant WHERE condition that feeds my report.

The problem is that Access is not reading the values selected from the ListBox. When I step through that line of code, the value is NULL.

So far:

```
Dim s As Variant
s = Me.City.Value & ""
```

This is where I know I wrong-turned, but, not having dealt with a multi-select ListBox before, I don't know the syntax to get the values read.

Next: Check for whether or not values are selected in List "s":

```
If s <> "" Then
```

Check for other parameters in the current WHERE condition. IF none exist, THEN

```
If c.WhereCondition = "" Then
c.WhereCondition =
```

Set WHERE Condition by comparing List values (which are Strings) to the Yes/No values of equivalent fields in Source table.

I have to compare the List values to the 70 fields in the table - to pull out those records that match.

No, there's not 1 field - say Cities, with 70 possible values. Instead, each of the 70 possible Cities is its own Yes/No field. I inherited this DB. It's how it was built.

Currently, my attempt at this looks like:

```
c.WhereCondition = "( City1 = -1 OR City2 = -1 OR City3 = -1 OR .....)
```

`IF there are parameters in the current WHERE clause, THEN compare values in List to Source table, AND APPEND result to WHERE condition with "AND"

```
ELSE
       c.WhereCondition = c.WhereCondition & " AND (City1 = -1 OR City2 = -1, OR ...)

    End If
    End If
```

I hope I was able to explain this well enough. The 1st problem is getting the values read. I won't know if my attempt at comparison is right or wrong without that.

Comment: I thought that a list of values was an array. If I'm wrong, my apologies, and I'll remove references to that.

Checking your link, now, also.

Comment: Stepping through, Access still shows the control as null

Dim frm As Form
Dim ctl As Control
Dim s As Variant
Set frm = Forms!ReportForm
Set ctl = frm!CITY

I also don't know why it's capitalizing CITY. It's proper case on the form. Either way, it's skipping over the For Each, because the control is still reading as Null.

Comment: Error - You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property ItemsSelected. Now why would it think the reference is invalid?

Comment: It returns type ListBox

Comment: Apologies, the *actual* name is COUNTY. I just used "City" to be obscure. But, being obscure is too much of a headache to maintain. That said Yes, TypeName(Forms!ReportForm!COUNTY) is listbox, and Forms!ReportForm!COUNTY.ItemsSelected.Count complains ItemsSelected is invalid there?

Comment: I have not. I'm reviewing your link, now. I won't be able to get back to this until tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, though. Back at it, today.

Comment: @JuniperSquared Are you using the report in conjunction with the form, or is it a separate product that you generate afterwards? If you're displaying the report on the form, it may be easier to filter it in the form after the user updates their selections in the list box using the `Report.Filter` and `Report.FilterOn` parameters.

Comment: It's a separate product that I generate afterwards. The form is used to compile the list of parameters - in vba - which gets stored in a variable. That variable is plugged into the code for the "GenerateReport - OnClick()" event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THIS took a LOT of breadcrumbs to get me here!

Solution:

```
Dim s As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim ctl As Control
Set ctl = Me.Counties

If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
    For Each s In ctl.ItemsSelected
        t.WhereCondition = ctl.ItemData(s) & " = -1"
    Next s
End If
```

1. I had to rename the control from County to Counties. Looks like the former was part of the report, and screwing everything else up. I did this after initially deleting & re-adding the control.
2. The comments here *really* helped. I just needed to figure out how to work with the properties in order to get what I wanted.
3. I have to compare 70 yes/no fields to the data, pulling out only those that return True. Hence the -1.

It compiles. It runs. Fingers crossed for data accuracy.

Thanks!